# Compare two dataframes and export unmatched data using pandas or other packages?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random

I have two dataframes and one is a subset of another one (picture below). I am not sure whether pandas can compare two dataframes and filter the data which is not in the subset and export it as a dataframe. Or is there any package doing this kind of task?

The subset dataframe was generated from `RandomUnderSampler` but the `RandomUnderSampler` did not have function which exports the unselected data. Any comments are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example? Example input data *as text* and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` with `keep=False` parameter:

Example:

```
>>> df1
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

>>> df2
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  6  7

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
   A  B
2  4  5
4  8  9
```